# I need to understand- on touch starting an animation in libgdx- basic concept

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I have a football player image who will kick a ball when user touches the screen. Not touch and hold just simple touch. So when user touches i need to start a libgdx animation which is in my create() method. I need to draw this animation in render(). So my code will be like this

**in render() method:**

```
elapsedTime += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();

if(Gdx.input.isTouched()) {
            if(lr.contains(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY())){
             batch.begin();
             batch.draw(kickAnimation.getKeyFrame(elapsedTime, false), 0, 0);
             batch.end();
         }
}
```

But i am not getting desired result. Am i conceptually correct? I am a javascript guy. This is a very simple problem to think about. I need to know the concept of making event based animation in libGDX way. Thanks.

Comment: What problem do you face? Does it work? Any Exceptions?... You should probably do this with a `Stage` and implement an `Actor` which will render your Animation on mouseover (event listener added).

Comment: When i touch i see only one sprite first time. My animation time is per frame 3 sec. So i was expecting one image first 3 sec and so on. No exceptions. Is it easier to deal with this kind of event based animation using scene2D?

Comment: Yes, scene2d would be the way to go here I think. Furthermore you are also increasing your elapsed time, even when you do not press the image... you should probably move that into the 2nd `if`

Comment: I put elapsed time in the second if. Now if i touch and hold only then i am getting the desired result. I want this result when i just simply touch.

Comment: Well, as a quick solution you could just switch a flag the first time you enter the 2nd if... but as I said, a more clean solution is `Stage` and a custom `Actor`

Comment: Thanks. I solved the problem with flags as you told. :) , feeling good!

Comment: Would you help me provide some working code for the same problem, i too am facing the same problem.